# Receive method on the input pin of directshow transform filter doesn't get called

Tags: directshow

I have my transform filter connected in the filter graph, but receive method of transform filter doesn't get called and there are no media samples arriving into my filter. What can be the cause of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unable to negotiate a content type?

Comment: Doens't look so. Graph is well connected. This starts to work when I:
1. Play video for a while (even without samples going out)
2. Stop.
3. Reconnect input and output pins on my filter
4. Start playing again.

So, it looks like media type given by Microsoft DTV-DVD decoder (which I'm receiving samples from), is not correct in the beginning. Still not sure how to solve this problem...I do not like this approach with pin reconnection.

Comment: There's the "synth" sample which is an example of a filter that can dynamically reconnect during a transmission.  It might hold some clues.